# Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator:

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to access CoreData from a class in Swift (not from a view - in views it is working fine using the environment object). I tried multiple approaches, but none worked.

I have implemented a DataController, which I want to use in both, views as well as in the mentioned class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class DataController: ObservableObject {

let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")

init(){
    container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
        if let error = error{
            print("Core Data failed to load \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

}
```

During app initialization functions in a class are being called inter alia to read data from WeatherKit, HealthKit and from CoreData. Within that class I have the function "readCoreData":

```
    func readCoreData(){
    
    var data = [ShoeEntity]()
    var controller = DataController()
    let moc = controller.container.viewContext
    let request = ShoeEntity.fetchRequest()
    
    do{
        
        data = try moc.fetch(request)
        print (data.count)
        
    }catch{
        print("Fetch failed")
    }
}
```

If this function is called, I don't get data from core data, but the following error in the console:

> Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x2805f04e0>

I assume it is because I need to use the environment object, but I am not sure how to do that in a class.

Would someone be able to help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Inject the DataController object into your class from the view  (where it is an EnvironmentObject) or add a static `shared` property to it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It might be a foolish question, but how exactly would I inject it into the class? I am calling the class from MainView as follows `import SwiftUI
@MainActor
struct MainView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc


    var body: some View {
        TabView{
            DashboardView()
                .environmentObject(HealthKitViewModel())
                .tabItem{
                    Label("Dashboard", systemImage: "list.dash")
                }`
Would it be as a parameter in the brackets of HealthKitViewModel?

Comment: So the DataController class is not an EnvironmentObject? But yes, you should pass it to the init of HealthKitViewModel then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have similar questions, I am posting how I resolved it.

I am passing the dataController from my MainView to the HealthKitViewModel as follows:

```
@EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController

var body: some View {
    
    TabView{
        DashboardView()
            .environmentObject(HealthKitViewModel(dataController: dataController))
            .tabItem{
                Label("Dashboard", systemImage: "list.dash")
            }}
```

And initializing the HealthKitViewModel class as follows

```
class HealthKitViewModel: ObservableObject{

var dataController: DataController

init(dataController: DataController){
    self.dataController = dataController
    
}
```